# f.g R module is image of f.g. free right module

Tags: ring-theory, proof-verification

Let $M$ be a f.g. right module over a ring, I need to show that $M$ is the homomorphic image of a f.g. free right $R$ module.

Is this as simple as just taking a basis of $M$ say $\Lambda=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ and forming the free module on this $F_\Lambda$ then simply defining the homomorphism that maps basis elements to basis elements?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes; it's that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "basis" of $M$, you should say "generating system". Otherwise the proof is correct. Convince yourself that *you* have understood the proof, it is worth nothing when we say that the proof is correct.